# Running script after DOM is finished

Tags: javascript, html

I'm dynamically creating menu items to be placed on the menu bar, based on the headers of external files, imported with an `XMLHttpRequest()`. As I navigate through the different pages, this menu bar is dynamically updated.

This works fine. 
I load each document into an individual `div` element, in a sort of stack of cards, and hide all but the `setVisible()` page.

```js
 window.onload = function(){
     loadContent("personalinfo");
     loadContent("academicalinfo");
     loadContent("employmentinfo");
     setVisible("academicalinfo");
     /*setMenues("academicalinfo");*/
}
```

The last action of `setVisible()` is to call `setMenues()`, which is responsible for reading all of the headers of said main window. This also works fine-ish.

```js
function loadMenues(file) {
     var rightmenu = document.getElementById("right-menu");
     while(rightmenu.firstChild){
         rightmenu.removeChild(rightmenu.firstChild);
     }
     [].forEach.call(document.getElementById(file).children,
         function(custompaddingchild) {
             /* searching for h1 and adding menu items happens here */
         }
     );
```

The problem arises when the DOM elements are not loaded yet, as when the page loads. Since there are no ElementsById(file) in the document element until the page is completely rendered, it fails to add the menu items onload.

I have tried adding an EventListener on the "load" event of the window and on the document, I have tried executing the function on the end of the body of the main page, and on the on `onload=` argument of `<body>` (which runs even before the subpages are captured, leaving me with a blank page instead of the actual content), but as it seems, none of them seems to happen after the page is completely loaded.

Adding a 2 second delay before running the functions is not an effective solution. Besides, adding a delay to the onload function will not affect the result, and will only increase loading time by two seconds.

Clicking any of the menues which update the menues work as intended. The only problem is onload.

```html
<div class="menu-item" onclick="setVisible('personalinfo');"><span>Personal information</span></div>
```

**How can I make sure the page delays the setVisible() function until after the page is rendered?** All the sources I've found claim the "load" event is triggered after the page is rendered, but it doesn't seem to be triggered in my case. The `DOMContentLoaded` event isn't triggered either, but I suspect I don't want this one. The `click` event, or a `scroll` event on the window, in contrast, do trigger correctly.

[Mozilla, Window: load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

[Javascript.info, Page: DOMContentLoaded, load, beforeunload, unload](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

**Edit:** As per request, here is loadContent():

```js
function loadContent(file) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", file+".html?_=" + new Date().getTime());
        request.onreadystatechange=function(){
                var loadedcontent = request.responseText;
                document.getElementById(file).innerHTML = loadedcontent;
        }
        request.send();
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Full code is available at https://github.com/mazunki/portfolioweb-stackoverflowquestion

Comment: Putting the call inside `window.onload` should work.

Comment: If the scripts are in an external script file you can use [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)

Comment: It does not work. Neither in Chrome, Chromium, or Firefox.

Comment: I'm assuming the three load methods are doing ajax?  So it's not a load issue.  It's an async issue.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I considered moving all my scripts to an external file. Now they are in the head of `index.html`. How can I use defer for this purpose?

Comment: you can use it like this: `<script src="abc.js" defer></script>`

Comment: What does the `loadContent();` method do?

Comment: Consider `loadedcontent` to be a string from the XMLHttpRequest(), and it basically does `document.getElementById(file).innerHTML = loadedcontent;`

Comment: What?  That's confusing.  Are you or are you not making an ajax request as part of that method call?

Comment: As I said, DOMContentLoaded doesn't seem to trigger. I tried a console.log(), and nothing came back.

Comment: are you attaching it to the `document` or the `window`, and can you paste an example of how you used it in your question?

Comment: I tried both of them. `window.addEventListener("load", function(){setVisible("personalinfo")});` never triggers. Neither does `console.log("foo")`.

Comment: Can we see the code of loadContent() please?

Comment: I'm using XMLHttpRequest() with a GET request to retrieve the file, in loadContent(). Check https://github.com/mazunki/portfolioweb-stackoverflowquestion to see the full code.

Comment: I have tried to defer the setMenues(), by moving it to a new file and adding defer to its call, but it doesn't seem to alter the result.

Comment: Show loadContent(), you need to use promises.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: @mazunki: Try doing it using DOMContentLoaded. I guess you are having some network call that doesnt complete at all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` and `load` events now do trigger, after moving them outside `window.onload`, but neither of them, regardless of whether I set it into the `defer` file or the other, accomplish my goal. Both of them do trigger (and if I understand correctly, the `defer` file shouldn't have triggered it...).

Comment: The issue is that the setMenues code is running before any of the content is loaded. This is because XmlHttpRequest runs asynchronously. You need to use Promises to ensure everything is loaded before you execute code which needs everything to be ready - see Luis' answer below

Answer (score 2):

You need to use promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Try this

```
function loadContent(file) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", file+".html?_=" + new Date().getTime());
        request.onreadystatechange=function(){
            var loadedcontent = request.responseText;
            document.getElementById(file).innerHTML = loadedcontent;

            resolve();
        }
        request.send();
    });
}

window.onload = function(){
    // when you finish all the content loading
    Promise.all([
        loadContent("personalinfo"),
        loadContent("academicalinfo"),
        loadContent("employmentinfo")
    ]).then(function() {
        // Load menu
        setVisible("academicalinfo");
        /*setMenues("academicalinfo");*/
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you tried to use the "library" https://github.com/ded/domready ? I think that is the simpliest solutuion for you.

Then you code would be:

```
function loadMenues(file) {
    domready(function () {
        var rightmenu = document.getElementById("right-menu");
        while(rightmenu.firstChild){
            rightmenu.removeChild(rightmenu.firstChild);
        }
        [].forEach.call(document.getElementById(file).children,
            function(custompaddingchild) {/* searching for h1 and adding menu items happens here */ }
        );
    })
}
```

Comment: I believe jQuery's `.load()` function would also do the job. Is there no built-in way to do it? I'm avoiding libraries.

Comment: @mazunki `$(document).ready()` do what you want, but I have imagined that you are not interested to use jQuery. This library that I suggested is the way to avoid jQuery, you can use that or see the code to find the better way to create your. But this library has only 26 lines opened and 571 bytes when minified.

Answer (score 0):

While this only stands as a fallback solution, and is not reliable over slow network connections, I solved it by placing the following inside the menuhandling.js file, called with `<script src="menuhandling.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>`:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    setVisible("personalinfo")
    /*setMenues("personalinfo")*/
},500) // half a second
```

`loadContent()` is called for all files in `stackhandling.js`, with no delay, and not `document.onload` nor `window.onload`.